# Trouble with fullcalendar hiding event text rather than wrapping

Tags: wordpress, plugins, fullcalendar

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here. I've been working with Fullcalendar (admittedly on a basic level) on our website. The code I've been using is as such:

```
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        editable: false,
        height: "auto",
        eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [

            {
                title: 'Event Title 1',
                start: '2014-09-26',
                end: '2014-09-29',
                color: '#266A2E'
            },              {
                title: 'Event Title 2',
                start: '2015-06-01',
                end: '2015-08-22',
                color: '#990000'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

```
body {
/*  margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;*/
}

#calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
```

Now this has been working fine for the time being with the exception that the names of the events will disappear if it is longer than the event. IE If the event only runs for one day and the title is Camp out at Millerton Lake then on the calendar it would show "Camp out at M". For the longest time I thought that was the unavoidable truth about it and just made sure to use creative titles if the event name ran too long. But now we are moving our hand coded website to a wordpress template and I found that there is a plugin that helps with this. I used https://wordpress.org/plugins/full-calendar-js/ and got it hooked up to a google calendar to allow quick and easy editing. Then I realized that on the WP site it was actually wrapping the text on the events onto multiple lines. I looked through the documentation again and tried many different google searches and searches here on Stackoverflow but cant' find anything that relates to event titles on the calendar wrapping as a setting. Am I missing something? Is there a line of code I can add on our older hand coded site that will force text to wrap instead of becoming hidden?

Comment: This probably isn't the best way to do it but after a month no one's offered any tips. I ended up finding that if I replace all the white-space: nowrap in the css to white-space:normal it now wraps text in titles. I guess this shows how much I still need to learn.